# Fetch request inside function. How to put it in ComponentDidMount?

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

As you can see, my handleSearchRequest function is calling an API , which is later called by an onClick event inside the IconButton tag.

How do I load the API inside ComponentWillMount, the way I can still write stuff on HandleSearchRequest like setState or something so Onclick can still call this function ?

```
class Searcher extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      query: '',
      application: null
    }

  }

  // componentDidMount () {
  //
  //
  //
  // }

  handleSearchRequest() {
    console.log('this.state', this.state);
    const BASE_URL = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term';
    const FETCH_URL = BASE_URL + '=' + this.state.query;
    console.log('FETCH_URL', FETCH_URL);

    fetch(FETCH_URL, {
      method: 'GET'
    })

      .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          const application = json.results[0];
          this.setState({application})
          console.log({application})
        });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div style={{position: 'relative'}}>
           <IconButton
             iconStyle={styles.smallIcon}
             style={styles.iconButton}
             onClick={() => this.handleSearchRequest()}
           >
               <Search color={black} />
           </IconButton>
        <TextField
          underlineShow={false}
          id="searchId"
          value={this.state.query}
          fullWidth={true}
          style={styles.textField}
          inputStyle={styles.inputStyle}
          hintStyle={styles.hintStyle}
          onChange={event => {this.setState({ query: event.target.value}) }}
          onKeyPress={event => {
            if (event.key === 'Enter') {
              this.handleSearchRequest()
            }
          }}
        />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        {
          this.state.application !== null
          ?
            <ResultItem
              {...this.props} {...this.state}
              application={this.state.application}
            />
          : <div></div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Searcher;
```

**EDIT**

this is the ResultItem component

```
class ResultItem extends Component {

componentDidMount () {

}
  render () {
    // console.log ('myProps', this.props);

    let application = {
      artistName: '',
      country: '',
      primaryGenreName: '',
      trackName: ''
    };

    if (this.props.application !== null) {
      application = this.props.application
    }

    return (
      <div>

        <Card style={{width:'30%'}}>
          <CardMedia>
            <div style={styles.appCard}/>
          </CardMedia>
          <FloatingActionButton
            style={styles.addButton}
            backgroundColor={'#CC0000'}
            >
            <ContentAdd />
          </FloatingActionButton>
          <CardTitle
            title={application.artistName}
                     subtitle="Application" />
          <CardText>
            <div>
              <div>Name:   <b>{application.artistName}      </b> </div>
              <div>Country:<b>{application.country}         </b> </div>
              <div>Genre:  <b>{application.primaryGenreName}</b> </div>
              <div>Song:   <b>{application.trackName}       </b> </div>
            </div>
          </CardText>
        </Card>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ResultItem;
```

Comment: what do you mean will not remember?

Comment: Like, If I put everything that the function has inside ComponentDidMount. then handleSearchRequest will only have 1 line const application = json.result [0] , but those 2 values (application and json) are not global variables, you know, like in ES5 ? it's a bad practice to do it that way anyway

Comment: When you want to store information, you store it in the component state using this.setState({ ... }). That is all. You can access the state from any component method using this.state.someProp

Comment: I was just trying to implement it like in this react pattern's book http://xzlearning.com/skills/6010 . as you can see they have the fetch call inside ComponentDidMount , just trying to apply the pattern there

Comment: There should be no problem calling a method from componentDidMount. What exactly are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifecycle method `componentDidMount` is typically used to fetch some initial data for your React component(s) to consume.

Given a method that makes an HTTP request to get some data. For instance,

```
fetchData() {
  fetch('https://www.somewhere.com/someResource')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
      this.setState({ someResource: responseJson });
    });
}
```

You can save the data into the component state using setState() as shown above, after fetching it.

Then simply call it from `componentDidMount()` to populate your component state with the initial data:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData();
}
```

You may call `fetchData()` again any time you would like to fetch that data again.

To access the resource from any component method (like in render()), use `this.state.someResource`.

**Update:**

If you have a component that relies on the data for its own rendering, then you should watch out. Initially there would be no data, so that component should not be rendered if it depends on that data and would give an error if it does not exist.

The solution is checking if the data exists before rendering anything.

**Example**

```
render() {
  if (!this.props.someResource) {
    // resource is not yet loaded
    return <div>Loading resource...</div>;
  }

  // Otherwise, if someResource has been fetched (i.e. is not undefined)
  // You can safely render the component that is dependent on it
  return (
    <MyComponent someResource={this.props.someResource} />
  );
}
```

Comment: I have tried that before. and I get a Cannot read property 'artistName' of undefined message. The important part of your answer makes sense, but how do I copy them ?

Comment: I just hit your API endpoint and it returns an object of the following format: `{
 "resultCount":0,
 "results": []
}`. 
Calling your fetch function in componentDidMount will do so with an empty query (because in your initial state, query is `''`), which will result in that response. The array `results` has no elements, so saying `const application = json.results[0];` will result in undefined. So you should consider the response from that API before implementing anything with it.

Comment: I cannot help you with the artistName part because it's not in the question. Sounds like you are trying to access something that does not exist. And it makes sense, since my previous comment says you queried the API but got no results. You should always make sure to check in your render function if you actually have any data to render. If not, then don't try to display some component that relies on that data existing. See the **Update** to my answer.

Comment: yeah makes sense if I put the function inside ComponentDidMount thats were the problems start, the value of query is ' ' (empty string) , which is supposed to be since this is a search input box the value is always gonna be empty. so I guess it makes sense NOT to put it on ComponentDidMount ?..however I feel like I can somehow put the value of this.state.application inside my render function , but how?...and do I need to worry about the this.state.query too ?...I have EDIT my question so you can see the artistName thing

Comment: Looking at your updated answer, the line `this.props.application !== null` is going to be true if `this.props.application` has value undefined. Because of that you are doing `application = undefined`, which is causing your error. You can solve this issue in two ways: (1) Simply do `this.props.application != null` because `undefined != null` is going to be false. (2) Replace `if (this.props.application !== null)` with `if (this.props.application)` because undefined evaluates to false.

Comment: Hi, just an update here I had said `setState` replaces the whole state, but that was wrong. The method that does that is `replaceState` (but it is likely deprecated). Sorry, I had confused it because I use Redux often and we have to watch out for not losing state. So setState will **merge** current and previous states together. That is, your query property will NOT have been lost if you said `this.setState({ application: 'whatever' });` Ref: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Cool , good to know thanks for the info. I'll be asking another question I've bren stuck in since your last answer. If you are interested that is. It's more like JS question again  which has to do with implementing material-ui chips inside my search box, which wants an array instead of my query='' which is a string. Anyway thanks again